# Unable to connect to Scylladb in Docker using C# driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, scylla, datastax-csharp-driver

I have created a single node ScyllaDB in docker, which is up and running, and below is my docker-compose commands:
version: "3"

```
 services:

 scylla-node1:
   container_name: scylla-node1
   image: scylladb/scylla
   restart: always
   command: --smp 2 --memory 1500M --broadcast-rpc-address 127.0.0.1 --listen-address 0.0.0.0 
   ports: 
       - 9042:9050
   networks:
   web:

   networks:
   web:
   driver: bridge
```

Reading the documentation for Scylla it recommends using the DataStax C# Driver for Apache Cassandra. So, I have used this in my solution. Following the basic examples, I am struggling to get it work. Thus,

```
   var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                 .AddContactPoints("0.0.0.0")
                 .Build();

  var session = cluster.Connect("sample_keyspace");
```

When the code reaches the Connect command it throws the following error
Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed (tried 0.0.0.0:9042: SocketException 'The requested address is not valid in its context.')'

Firstly, I can connect to Scylla through the CSQL Utility and can create a Keyspace and then run a query to confirm that the Keyspace has been created.

Is this a problem with C# Driver or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So when you run Docker, your container gets its own IP.  Have you tried connecting to port 9042 on _that_ IP?  You'll also need to open up that port from your container to the outside world.

Comment: The driver by default uses port 9042 unless you specify it. I would have thought the port setting in the compose allows access to the IP and port,  doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, if you `EXPOSE` it in your dockerfile that's part of it.  But you might also need to specify it when running the container...`docker run --name cassandra-node1 --net=cassandra_network -p 9042:9042`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a networking issue to me because your Docker container doesn't appear to be configured correctly.

The problem is that the C# driver (your application) is not able to connect to the container because there is no network connectivity. That is what this exception means:

```
Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed (tried 0.0.0.0:9042: \
  SocketException 'The requested address is not valid in its context.')'
```

I assume "CSQL utility" is a typo. The reason you are able to connect using cqlsh is because you are most likely connecting with:

```
$ docker exec -it scylla-node1 cqlsh
```

which isn't the same as connecting remotely. To be fair I'm making an assumption as you didn't provide details.

You've configured the container with `--broadcast-rpc-address 127.0.0.1` so it will only listen for client connections on `localhost`. This means that you can't use `0.0.0.0` as the contact point.

I've also noted that you've mapped the container port `9050` to host port `9042`:

```
   ports: 
       - 9042:9050
```

By default, Cassandra listens for client connections on port `9042`, not `9050`. If nothing is listening on port `9050`, there's nothing for the driver to connect to and will also lead to `NoHostAvailableException`. Cheers!